# Проблема с релизной версией приложения

Tags: android, firebase-database

Разрабатывал приложение на android с использованием firebase и столкнулся с проблемой. Когда я запускаю приложение на телефоне в режиме отладки, то всё работает нормально, как и задумывалось, приложение загружает данные из базы данных. Далее, когда я собрал apk-файл, скинул на телефон, установил и попробовал запустить приложение, оно вылетело с ошибкой. Причём вылетело именно на моменте подключения к базе данных. Вообще не понимаю, в чём загвоздка... База данных открыта для чтения и редактирования.
[image: правила базы данных]

Вот содержимое файлов build.gradle уровня проекта и модуля:

build.gradle(Project:MyProject)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nix.shedulefirebaseapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: По идее у вас должен быть файл googleplay-services.json в проекте. Который вы из FireBase консоли взяли. Вот его надо, по идее, поменять сразу после добавления отпечатка релизного ключа в настроках проекта в консоли FireBase

Comment: Неплохо посмотреть в логе, что за ошибка. Но да, если изменился только ключ, то нужно проверить, что в консоли Firebase добавлен релизный ключ, и после этого в приложении обновлен .json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас не добавлен релизный ключ в консоли Firebase. Вам нужно добавить релизный ключ, а затем скачать новый json файл